# I want to grep out a text string from many files, how can I run a loop for this

Tags: text-processing, files, grep

I have a thousand `.xyz` files, all numerical data and in the same directory. Some of them have the text string "END" at the very end of them. I'm not sure how to loop a `grep` command so that it removes the "END" and creates a new file, while appending something to end of the original filename.

Example of the last lines of some of my files

```
-1.10949170 55.68890280 -67.60000000
-0.92807500 55.64095280 -89.80000000
-0.95770560 55.66495830 -82.40000000
-0.90995000 55.63676110 -94.00000000
-1.03738890 55.65107220 -70.20000000
END
```

I want this (removing the END) from many files

```
-1.10949170 55.68890280 -67.60000000
-0.92807500 55.64095280 -89.80000000
-0.95770560 55.66495830 -82.40000000
-0.90995000 55.63676110 -94.00000000
-1.03738890 55.65107220 -70.20000000
```

Original file name: `survey_2015_xxx.xyz`
New file name:     `survey_2015_xxx_s.xyz`

Answer (score 3):

If your `head` supports negative offsets:

```
for file in *.xyz; do
  if [ "$(tail -n 1 < "$file")" = END ]; then
    head -n -1 < "$file" > "${file%.xyz}_s.xyz"
  fi
done
```

(if it doesn't, replace `head -n -1` with `sed '$d'`).

You can make it more efficient with `ksh93`:

```
for file in *.xyz; do
  if IFS= read -r last4 < "$file" <#((EOF-4)) <#((here=CUR)) &&
    [ "$last4" = END ]; then
    command /opt/ast/bin/head -c "$here" < "$file" > "${file/%.xyz/_s\0}"
  fi
done
```

As it's only using builtin commands.

If your file system supports reflink copies (that is copying files where the data is not duplicated until modified which here would save time and disk space), you could do, still with `ksh93` and with GNU `cp`:

```
for file in *.xyz; do
  if IFS= read -r last4 < "$file" <#((EOF-4)) &&
    [ "$last4" = END ]; then
    newfile=${file/%.xyz/_s\0}
    cp --reflink=auto -- "$file" "$newfile" &&
      : 1<>; "$newfile" >#((EOF-4))
  fi
done
```

That is, we're making a reflink copy and truncating it 4 bytes from the end.

Answer (score 1):

An `ed` alternative, because you only live once:

```
for f in *.xyz; do
    printf '%s\n' ';g/END/d\' "w ${f%.xyz}_s.xyz" q | ed -s "$f"
done
```

Filename caveats:

- Filenames  cannot begin with `!`, otherwise `ed` will attempt to pipe the buffer into a command.
- Since `ed` uses blank characters to delimit the `w` command from its pathname argument, leading blanks in filenames will not be preserved.
- Filenames with newlines will cause problems since `ed` uses newlines to delimit commands.

In a sane world, none of these limitations are relevant. Alas ...

Comment: Yeah, `ed` can definitely do this job ... With some escaping and a slight change of code you can work around those limitations and deal with pretty much any kind of filename. Not worth it though.

Answer (score 0):

Just other solution using `sed`

```
for file in *.xyz
do
    if [ "$(sed -e '$!d' $file)" = END ]
    then
        sed -e '$d' $file > $file_s.xyz
    fi
done
```